# Panoramic Image Photogrametry: How to calculate range?

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing

Assume that I took two panoramic image with vertical offset of H and each image is presented in equirectangular projection with size Xm and Ym. To do this, I place my panoramic camera at position say A and took an image, then move camera H meter up and took another image.

I know that a point in image 1 with coordinate of X1,Y1 is the same point on image 2 with coordinate X2 and Y2(assuming that X1=X2 as we have only vertical offset).

My question is that How I can calculate the range of selected of point (the point that  know its X1and Y1 is on image 1 and its position on image 2 is X2 and Y2 from the Point A (where camera was when image no 1 was taken.).

Comment: I think a diagram would help! Is H in metres or degrees? Is H measured at the vertical plane of the camera, or at the vertical plane of the known point? If the points are vertically offset, surely they will have the same X and differing Y values? Your last sentence doesn't make sense - what is *the range of selected of point*? Selected `what` of point? Range from where - from where the camera is or where the point is?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks. I add more information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it - hold on!!!

Key thing `y` = focal length of your lens - now I can do it!!!

So, I think your question can be re-stated more simply by saying that if you move your camera (on the right in the diagram) up `H` metres, a point moves down `p` pixels in the image taken from the new location.

Like this if you imagine looking from the side, across you taking the picture.

[image]

If you know the micron spacing of the camera's CCD from its specification, you can convert `p` from pixels to metres to match the units of `H`.

Your range from the camera to the plane of the scene is given by `x` + `y` (both in red at the bottom), and

```
x=H/tan(alpha)

y=p/tan(alpha)
```

so your range is

```
R = x + y = H/tan(alpha) + p/tan(alpha)
```

and

```
alpha = tan inverse(p/y)
```

where y is the focal length of your lens. As `y` is likely to be something like 50mm, it is negligible, so, to a pretty reasonable approximation, your range is

```
H/tan(alpha)
```

and

```
alpha = tan inverse(p in metres/focal length)
```

Or, by similar triangles

```
Range =     H x focal length of lens
        --------------------------------
         (Y2-Y1) x CCD photosite spacing
```

being very careful to put everything in metres.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I find H? when I have two pictures, I have Y1 and Y2, As I used an application like Hugin to stitch my images, I don't have exact values for focal length and CCD phtosite spacing (I think Hugin process to get a good stitch will changes these values). I can definitely test the method, if I know how to calculate H, as I can use focal length of input camera and its CCD photosit spacing in this formula for testing.

Comment: I thought `H` was how far you moved your camera up between the shots.

Comment: Thanks, I will do a test and will report back if I had any success. Y1 and Y2 are pixel values? as the images are in panoramic format, I believe I need to convert them to angles, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shot in the dark, given my understanding of the problem at hand you want to do something similar to computer stereo vision, I point you to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_stereo_vision to start. Not sure if this is still possible to do in the manner you are suggesting, it sounds like you may need some more physical constraints but I do remember being able to correlate two 2d points in images after undergoing a strict translation. Think :

```
lambda[x,y,1]^t = W[r1, tx;r2, ty;ry, tz][x; y; z; 1]^t
```

Where `lamda` is a scale factor, `W` is a 3x3 matrix covering the intrinsic parameters of your camera, `r1, r2, and r3` are row vectors that make up the 3x3 rotation matrix (in your case you can assume the identity matrix since you have only applied a translation), and `tx, ty, tz` which are your translation components.

Since you are looking at two 2d points at the same 3d point `[x,y,z]` this 3d point is shared by both 2d points. I cannot say if you can rationalize the actual x,y, and z values particularly for your depth calculation but this is where I would start.

Comment: I can not understand what you mean. Can you please elaborate? How can I find x,y,z using parameters that I have, How to find camera intrinsic when images are created by Hugin and not a single camera?

Comment: As far as finding the camera's intrinsic parameters, I assumed from your question that you are using the same camera to capture both images, the original, and then the one taken from a position H above the original. In this case the intrinsic parameters will be the same for both images and can be found through Camera Calibration Techniques which I would say falls outside the scope of this question but I would direct you to http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zhang/Papers/TR98-71.pdf. As for the affect of Hugin on this problem, I cannot say how their panorama stitching will affect it.