# Measuring size of object with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, measurement

I have calibrated camera and undistorted image, object on image is binarized and only contours are shown. Then I use rectangle to get the dimension of the object -> I have distance in pixels. The camera has fixed position and after calibration the distance from object is fixed too.

[image: highlither]

Size of the red rectangle ~ 81×630 pixels.

Is there any way to transform pixels to millimeters using only OpenCV calibration or should I measure pixel size of object with known dimension?

Comment: What you are asking for is physically impossible: unless you know the distance between focal point and what you are measuring, you cannot with a monocular camera measure things: something 1m wide that is 2m away will have the same image (pixel) size than an object of 2m that is 1m away. Or does your question need some clarifications ?

Comment: Camera is always on the same place. I thought that due to calibration I'll be able to measure something, because there is known size of calibration grid.

Comment: @kebs I think something has gone wrong with your analogy - I can't believe a smaller object that is further away will subtend the same angle as a larger object that is closer.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Oops, correct ! It's exactly the opposite, I meant "something 2m wide that is 2m away will have the same image (pixel) size than an object of 1m that is 1m away."

Comment: Do you know the focal length of the lens and the sensor size in mm and also in pixels? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28820333/2836621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a capture of a caliper with the same camera options. Then, you might match the distance with the pixel count. Then, you could compute the corresponding distance of your object pixels in your image using your matching.

Sample caliper image:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is feasible, unless you know some camera parameters, as mentioned in the comments and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819101/panoramic-image-photogrametry-how-to-calculate-range/28820333#28820333). Also, to be accurate, you have to deal with the distortion in straight lines

Comment: I don't know the camera parameters, but pictures are undistorted - I use OpenCV calibration grid. I'll try this solution.

Comment: Ok, I've measured pixel size of one circle on calibration grid after calibration (it's similar to your answer, because I know the real size of it), measured height by OpenCV is 135,84 mm and real is 135,1 mm.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the actual size of the object you are looking at with the ruler, then multiply the number of pixels of the object you are picturing in a number that is the same as the actual size
And because the camera is calibrated, the odds you find are right for everyone.